# How to use data from a callback function in another function

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to take the x, y, and yaw value from the callback function and use them in a different function. Although when I run the code I have below,  all the variables below return a value of 0.
From my thought process, I think the global variables should be accessible for the void move() function as well, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Can someone tell what's wrong?

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "turtlesim/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

float x = 0, y = 0, yaw = 0 ;

void callback(const turtlesim::Pose::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    x = msg->x;
    y = msg->y;
    yaw = msg->theta;
    
}

void move()
{
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        ROS_INFO("x: [%f], y: [%f], yaw: [%f]", x, y, yaw);
    }
}

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "pose");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/turtle1/pose", 1000, callback);
        move();
        ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343938/how-to-use-data-from-a-callback-function-in-another-function/) by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2020-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So going line by line here to help show you the flow of the issue:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "pose");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/turtle1/pose", 1000, callback);
```

All good, initializing ROS, getting a nodehandle, creating a subscriber object and giving it the callback function to call. The spinner would then throw new messages received on that topic of that type to the function.

```
move() {while (ros::ok()) {...}}
```

Well, this is going to block infinitely. And while you're going to exit when ROS shuts down, no where in this infinite loop do you actually call a `spin` or `spinOnce` for the ROS messages building up to be processed (with a 1000 message queue size).

```
ros::spin();
```

Then you spin. This spin will only be called once your `move()` method exits (ie you end the program) so you're only just then starting to process messages.

What you could do instead is call `ros::spinOnce()` in your `move()` function and remove the `ros::spin()` from the end of your main function. That way you're processing messages in the callback and printing some values to screen.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-02-17**:
Would it be okay if I call `ros::spin()` before calling the `move()`?
Would that produce the same result?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-17**:
No. Spin is blocking and will not return until the session is ended. Think of `spin()` being a while loop with a spin and a sleep (its more complex than that, but essentially).

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-02-18**:
Thank you for the explanation.